# What does this Facebook comment mean: "As a top fan, I don't really have anything to say."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, clauses

> As a top fan, I don't really have anything to say. I just wrote it to protect my badge.

I saw this joke comment in Facebook comments and I don't understand it.

I can't see how the two clauses relate.

Comment: Without the rest of the context, we can't really guess why your cited writer thinks "being a top fan" somehow "explains" why he has nothing to say. Perhaps the subject matter is some damning evidence against whoever he's a "top fan" of - and since he can no longer justify his hero in the face of such revelations, he'd rather keep quiet, ignore the matter, and hope it goes away.

Comment: He said "As a top fan, i dont really have anything to say. I just wrote it to protect my badge

Comment: If that's all, he's either a woolly thinker or not very proficient in the use of English. The normal implication of the cited construction is that the "role, identity" *(**a top fan**)* justifies or explains the following assertion (that the writer has nothing to say, here). But that implication simply doesn't make sense with your cited text. What he ***could*** have reasonably written would be something like ***Although** I'm a top fan, I have nothing to say* (a contextually meaningful ***contrast***, since we'd normally expect committed "top fans" to have opinions they want to express).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook gives "Top Fan" badges to people who post a lot in a community (or hit "Like," or share posts into or from that community's Facebook Group or Facebook Page.  It only judges quantity, not quality.   I seem to be granted this Top Fan status on a lot of pages for what does not seem like significant engagement, but Webtrickz states:

> For this, you have to interact a lot with a page by liking or reacting to a post, commenting, sharing, and watching the page’s videos...  For instance, there are users who became a top fan just by liking the posts while those engaging via comments, sharing, etc. haven’t got it. To increase your chances, make sure you’re consistently active on a certain page.

For the original post, the user was probably trying to just keep his badge active..

> Also, you need to keep engaging with a particular page to maintain your top fan status

OR he was commenting on how little the status means:  Why would anyone pay attention to him?  He's not a puppeteer or even certified muppet expert (or whatever is relevant for this page) - he's just a guy with a digital "sticker" by his name.

Source: personal experience, plus [this](https://webtrickz.com/facebook-top-fan-badge/).

Work blocks Facebook, so I couldn't get their official descriptions.  Apparently, it's been a feature since 2018.

Answer (score 0):

The person is admitting to writing something just to keep their status as a top fan, which requires them to make a certain number of comments or to perform other actions in a group or on a page.

So the joke is that they are making a self-confession while they are doing something to get around the intention of the rules.